# SoundJS - assigning sounds to variables

Tags: audio, jquery-animate, createjs, soundjs

I am loading several mp3 files using loadManifest, but I am a bit confused by how I'd assign the loaded sounds to variables.  Can I use createInstance here?

My code currently looks like this:

```
var myRoot = this;

var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
queue.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
queue.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);

queue.loadManifest([{ src: "media/file1.mp3", id: "sound1" },
                    { src: "media/file2.mp3", id: "sound2" },
                    { src: "media/file3.mp3", id: "sound3" }]);

function handleFileLoad(event) {    
    // assign each sound to unique variable
    myRoot.sound1 = createjs.Sound.createInstance("sound1");
    myRoot.sound2 = createjs.Sound.createInstance("sound2");
    myRoot.sound3 = createjs.Sound.createInstance("sound3");
}

function handleComplete(event) {
    // start playing sound1
    myRoot.sound1.play();
}
```

How can I create an instance of a sound using it's ID and assign it to a variable that I can easily access later?  Do I need to register sounds before I am able to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following line was missing, and is all that was required for that code to work:

```
queue.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
```

That, and it's better to move variable assignments out to handleComplete function

The complete working code looks like this:

```
var myRoot = this;

var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();
queue.installPlugin(createjs.Sound); 
queue.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);

queue.loadManifest([{ src: "media/file1.mp3", id: "sound1" },
                    { src: "media/file2.mp3", id: "sound2" },
                    { src: "media/file3.mp3", id: "sound3" }]);

function handleComplete(event) {
    // assign each sound to unique variable
    myRoot.sound1 = createjs.Sound.createInstance("sound1");
    myRoot.sound2 = createjs.Sound.createInstance("sound2");
    myRoot.sound3 = createjs.Sound.createInstance("sound3");
    // start playing sound1
    myRoot.sound1.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `createjs.Sound.play(id)` method returns an instance of the sound object.

So you can do:

```
myRoot.sound1 = createjs.Sound.play(id, [createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_ANY], [delay], [offset], [loops], [volume]);
```

After this, you can use the reference to manipulate the sound freely. For example:

```
myRoot.sound1.volume = 0.5;
myRoot.sound1.addEventListener("complete", handleSoundComplete);
myRoot.sound1.play();
myRoot.sound1.stop();
```

By using this you also have several other possibilities, like saving the sound instances in an array to reuse them, or you can play them all the time by their IDs instead using a custom play method.

Also, if you are using the manifest loader to load the sound, you do not need to register each sound individually, since they will be registered automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  This works great if I only have one sound to load, but since there are several mp3 that I needed to load them as a manifest.  My problem was a really silly one - I just forgot to include one line to make it all work.  Thank you very much for taking time to look at this post and to post an answer!